# COUNT help in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table: Table is: probe

probe

------ProbeID------TranscriptID----

```
   2655       4555555
   2600       5454542
   2600       4543234
   2344       56595959
```

...etc

How do I count the probes per each transcript? Importantly, same probe can associate with more than one transcript.

I need the final output to be the actual number of probes. By that I mean, the Total number (i.e. 12340) and not the actual table with the probes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count number of `TranscriptID` associated with each ProbeID you can use `group by` as:

```
SELECT ProbeID, count(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY ProbeID;
```

And if you just want the count of distinct `ProbeID` you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProbeID) 
FROM tab
```

Comment: This will provide the actual table. How would you get the actual number? For instance, when I want to get the number of unique ProbeID in the table, I'd do the following: "SELECT count(distinct ProbeID) FROM probe". This give me the number 745444.